# Search Partially between two maps

Tags: java, hashmap

I have two Hashmaps `Map1<List,List>` and `Map2<List,List>` , Key List contains two elements for both the maps - String `name and time`.

I want to iterate  through Map1 and check if key of map1 is contained in map 2, but since my key has 2 elements ,I want to compare only on basis of time.

```
for (Entry<List, List> entry : Map1.entrySet()) {
        if("Map2.contains(entry.getKey().get(1))"){
        }
}
```

`example: Map1 ,Key1: student1, 14:30:20(time of entering class)
Map1 ,Key2: student1, 14:30:12
Map2 ,Key1: student2, 14:30:13
Map2 ,Key2: student2, 14:30:20`

Note: It is just an example: I want to see whether student1 and student2 entered the class at same time.
In this example 1st and last rows match should return true

Is this possible ? if yes,What should be my if condition?

Comment: You might want to consider your `key` again. `List` as key is not good choice.

Comment: You'd essentially have to do a linear search unless you provide more info, like the map type and any comparator it may be using.

Comment: And yeah, potentially mutable keys are a terrible idea

Comment: I have a file on which I am iterating, It doesnt has any unique element, that is why I had to create two elements as key

Comment: @chetnarustagi provide sample data so we can get more insight.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything, except that this is an xy problem. Please ask a proper question  explaining what you are actually trying to achieve. Be sure to include samples of the input and a description of your current attempt with code included

Comment: This is a perfect example of why showing actual code is a good idea.

Comment: edited my question with sample example

Comment: What's the structure of the value-list in the maps? Are these just strings for the different data-fields of one student? Are the fields name and time only present in the key-list or also in the value-list?

Comment: Both name and time are Strings, no they are not present in value-list, they are only in key-list. In value-list there are 5 values - all are strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's unclear what you really want, here some suggestion:

1. Create a class for the "students" with all data-fields (Note: You could use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) for `time`)

   ```
   public class Student {
       private LocalTime time;
       private String name;

       public Student(LocalTime time, String name) {
           this.time = time;
           this.name = name;
       }

       public LocalTime getTime() {
           return time;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       //TODO add the other fields
   }
   ```
2. When you need to access the students not only over the the *time*, then just store them in a `List<Student>`. (Since you wrote *"I have a file on which I am iterating, It doesnt has any unique element"*)
3. If you need to group the objects you can use the Java8-Stream-API. For example:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
           new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:12"),"s1"),
           new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:12"),"s2"),
           new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:13"),"s3"));

       Map<LocalTime,List<Student>> groupByTime = students.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getTime));

       // print the grouped students to System.out
       for(Entry<LocalTime,List<Student>> entry : groupByTime.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println(entry.getKey());
           for(Student student : entry.getValue()) {
               System.out.println("\t"+student.getName());
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. When you have two lists without any duplicated entry you can simple concatenated them and then group:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<Student> students1 = Arrays.asList(
               new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:20"),"s1"),
               new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:12"),"s1"));

       List<Student> students2 = Arrays.asList(
               new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:13"),"s2"),
               new Student(LocalTime.parse("14:30:20"),"s2"));

       Map<LocalTime,List<Student>> groupByTime = Stream.concat(students1.stream(), students2.stream())
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getTime));


       for(Entry<LocalTime,List<Student>> entry : groupByTime.entrySet()) {
           System.out.println(entry.getKey());
           for(Student student : entry.getValue()) {
               System.out.println("\t"+student.getName());
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**This will be your conditional statement**

```
if(map2.containsKey(entry.getKey().get(1)){
}
```

*Your condition was wrong so I corrected it.*

Comment: @chetnarustagi double quotes are generally given to strings as far as I know,how are you using this statement using if ?It doesn't make sense.

Comment: this should be a comment instead of a answer, and did you try your answer? you haven't read the question carefully.

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer    This will not work as it will compare map2 complete key with 1st element of  keyList 1, which will always return false

Comment: @ChaojunZhong should I delete it then?

Comment: @CalculusProgrammer you can update your answer then.

Comment: @ChaojunZhong can you tell me exactly what I have to include in my answer?He has asked for the condition which I have provided.